# Delete rows with certain conditions in Python

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I'm doing research on a certain keyword of Twitter messages, using the Twitter search API for Python.

Now I have a large CSV file, consisting of messages containing this keyword, but also with the keyword in the username. So these messages aren't about the keyword, the keyword just happens to be in the username.

Example:

- A corrrect row in my csv:
  *@Koningsbruggen tweeted: @CGCommunicatie are you guys in "KEYWORD"?*
- An incorrect row in my csv:
  @"KEYWORD"_lady tweeted: @rvanbommel yes thats okay

How can I delete the latter row using Python code?
I got a csv with 120K rows, so it would be nice to automatically delete these incorrect rows.

Comment: *How can I delete the latter row using Python code?* Yes you can. Try to write a script that read the data and when you stuck on filter rows come back with a new question.

Comment: [Open the file and iterate over it](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), [```split```](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) each line on the colon (```:```), [```if```](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) the line meets your criteria, [save it in a list](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input file is line by line list of the messages:

```
ATamsterdam_lady tweeted: ATrvanbommel ja dikke vlokken
ATKoningsbruggen tweeted: ATCGCommunicatie zitten jullie in Amsterdam?
ATJustoRasta tweeted: febovers ... AT Leidseplein - Amsterdam Centrum t.co/KCUCzj2dWq
AT7Ash_bash tweeted: #HENNY AND AMSTERDAM TONIGHT
```

Then you could use following Python code:

```
input_file = 'twitter.txt'
output_file = 'result.txt'
keyword = 'Amsterdam'

with open(input_file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    message = line.split('tweeted: ')[1]
    if keyword.lower() in message.lower():
        with open(output_file, 'a') as myfile:
            myfile.write(line)
```

Generated output file contains line by line text with included 'Amsterdam' only in the 'message' part:

```
ATKoningsbruggen tweeted: ATCGCommunicatie zitten jullie in Amsterdam?
ATJustoRasta tweeted: febovers ... AT Leidseplein - Amsterdam Centrum t.co/KCUCzj2dWq
AT7Ash_bash tweeted: #HENNY AND AMSTERDAM TONIGHT
```

Comment: my input is a csv that looks like:

    ATamsterdam_lady tweeted: ATrvanbommel ja dikke vlokken
    ATKoningsbruggen tweeted: ATCGCommunicatie zitten jullie in Amsterdam?
    ATJustoRasta tweeted: febovers ... AT Leidseplein - Amsterdam   Centrum http://t.co/KCUCzj2dWq
    AT7Ash_bash tweeted: #HENNY AND AMSTERDAM TONIGHT!

So just 1 Twitter message every line.

Comment: @mvh, I updated the script according to your comments. Should be worked now.

Comment: My file by file is line by line as you said, but without the ; at the end of each line. Furthermore, I would also like to get my output line by line. Do I just need to change:

    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='\n')  

So the delimiter? Thanks

Comment: @mvh, if you don't have ';' or another delimiter in the file, then its just a simple text. You don't need to deal with the CSV stuff. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you loaded your tweets into a pandas dataframe then this can be filtered very easily and quickly:

```
In [11]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'tweet':['@Koningsbruggen tweeted: @CGCommunicatie are you guys in "KEYWORD"?', '@"KEYWORD"_lady tweeted: @rvanbommel yes thats okay']})
df
Out[11]:
                                               tweet
0  @Koningsbruggen tweeted: @CGCommunicatie are y...
1  @"KEYWORD"_lady tweeted: @rvanbommel yes thats...
```

We can call the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) methods to `split` the tweet and filter them using `contains`:

```
In [25]:

df[df.tweet.str.split('tweeted:').str[1].str.contains('KEYWORD')]
Out[25]:
                                               tweet
0  @Koningsbruggen tweeted: @CGCommunicatie are y...
```

There are many methods to load data into pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html